# Same XP when evolving vs catching a pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I evolve a pokemon and it turns into a pokemon that's not registered in my pokedex, will I get the same XP, candies, and stardust that I'd get if I caught one in the wild?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If not in your Pokédex, you get extra 500 xp, the same as catching it, but catching also provides candies (3) and 100 stardust, while evolving only gives 1 candy.

Comment: Do note, you will receive a single candy when evolving.

Comment: And evolving will also (obviously) remove your old pokemon and the cost of evolving

Answer (score 22):

Evolving will give the following:

- 500 xp
- 1 candy
- the evolved pokemon

Catching will give the following:

- 100 xp
- 100 stardust
- 3 candies
- bonus exp based upon the throw
- the caught pokemon

Both instances will give an additional 500 xp if the resulting pokemon is not yet in your pokedex.

So they don't give the same thing. Exp: yes. Candies: no. Stardust: no.